# How to get file name of second latest file in a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use this command to get file name of latest created file in my folder:

```
@for /f %%i in ('dir myFolder\*.log /b/a-d/od/t:c') do @set LAST_LOG=%%i
```

But I need the file name of SECOND latest file in my folder.

How to get file name of second latest created file in folder `myFolder`?

Answer (score 1):

reverse the sort order, skip the first and take the first of the remaining (the following are ignored because of `if defined ...`)

```
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('dir myFolder\*.log /b/a-d/o-d/t:c') do @(if not defined LASTbutone_LOG set "LASTbutone_LOG=%%i")
```